# Lost rwe permssions from ntsf partition shared by Ubuntu 22.04 and Win 10. What is the syntax to re-establish rwe permissions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, 22.04

Currently I only have read permission on my 'S Drive'. This loss of permission happened recently, not sure why?
I am the only one on the computer. There is no /etc/fstab file.

The mount point is /mnt/2ECFD9016A88AD0A

What syntax do I use to restore rwe permissions as owner to this partition and files. I am not afraid to use the terminal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Boot into Win and shut down it properly.

Comment: As Pilot6 says. Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: None of the suggestions worked.